# How to divide class into groups to maximize the level of collaboration?

Tags: combinatorics

Question: The class of 15 is going to be divided into groups. There are 3 groups of 4 and 1 group of 3. Each week the group members will switch who they work with. Find a way to maximize collaborating with the most people in the class. There can only be 12 rotations.

As i was solving, I divided the group and named them. Group 1 had four people consisting of 1A, 1B, 1C, 1D. I did this for the three other groups. My first instinct was to use permutations to solve. However, 4*3*2*1 does not seem likely. Also, I left out a key fact; that there must be **12 rotations** **every week** I'm not sure how this can be mathematically solved.

Comment: Is a rotation one person moving or any number of people moving?

Comment: any number of people moving

Comment: It makes it more symmetric to consider a class of $16$ students and four groups of four.  At the end, just erase the last student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's enumerate the children using A-O just so that each person can be represented by a letter and then take some pieces of paper that you can divide into 4 sections that each section represents a group.  At least this would be the easiest way for me to picture this in my head and then each piece of paper can represent a rotation.

While you could start with the easy part of:

Group 1: A,B,C,D

Group 2: E,F,G,H

Group 3: I,J,K,L

Group 4: M,N,O

Then you could rotate by flipping the matrix-like outline above:

Group 1: A,E,I,M

Group 2: B,F,J,N

Group 3: C,G,K,O

Group 4: D,H,L

Diagonals from either may be another route to getting another group(Visually this is starting at one letter and then going over one and down one in theory):

Group 1: M,J,G,D

Group 2: A,F,K,O

Group 3: N,L,E,B

Group 4: C,H,I

The key is to find the other groupings so that each person is working with others that they haven't worked before initially and then allow some duplication as at this point, each person has worked with 7, as H has been in the 3some group twice now, to 9, as some of the others that stayed with 4 got 3 new people each time, other people as those in Group 4 get slightly shortchanged but I'd think this is a typical Scheduling problem in some regards.